# How to log where the exceptions have been thrown using Grafana?

Tags: exception, logging, grafana, dashboard, serilog

In Grafana I am trying to log exactly where the exceptions are thrown. This way in my dashboard I can have a panel that shows me where the different exceptions are thrown.

Printing out the stack trace is of course a possibility, but is it simply often too long and I would like a more neat approach.

Cutting down the log string length isn't intuitively an option, since "exception-paths" have different lengths and to a cut, that makes sense, the lengths need to be the same.

I am currently using serilog, but can't manage a way to do what I want (except from printing the entire stack trace) - therefore I am wondering if anyone else have a better solution?

I am coding in Visual Studio, C#, btw - just for clarification.